# CommonsMultipartFile in Grails

Tags: grails, file-upload

In my Grails application there is a feature to upload some files.

When I don't choose anything to upload, the value of `params` in the controller's method is:

```
params:[fileupload:org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile@44c1e51d]
```

The value of `request.getMultiFileMap().fileupload.isEmpty()` is also `false`.

Why is `fileupload` filled when I didn't choose anything to upload?

Here is my view .gsp code:

```
<g:form url="[resource:adsInstance, action:'save']" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
   <input class="inputFiles" type="file" name="fileupload" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
</g:form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `request.getFile('fileupload').isEmpty()` instead of `request.getMultiFileMap().fileupload.isEmpty()`

Comment: Worked fine  , but why `request.getMultiFileMap().fileupload` has value although i didn't choose any file ?